# How do you set the 'look-and-feel' of a winform app hosted in IE to the 'aero' style of controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, controls, look-and-feel

Is there a way to have a windows form app hosted in IE use the 'look-and-feel' of the current OS/browser, similar to how everything looks when the app is run in the debugger?  For instance I'm debugging in VS2008 and it looks great, but when I view the app in IE7 or IE8 on Vista or Win7 all the controls look like Netscape navigator circa 1996.  Buttons, labels, scrollbars, datagrids etc, is there a general setting to change this?

I'm currently compiling for .Net 2.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the app in the debugger, it goes through your Program.cs.Main() method which call System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles().  Are you coming in via some different entry point when hosting in IE?  One that would not call System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles() perhaps?  If so, you can add the call to EnableVisualStyles()--just make sure it's only called once or it will puke on you.  Wrap it in a Try-Catch and gulp any System.InvalidOperationException.